# Is there a way to calculate how much Harddrive Space is needed for one's entire Steam Library?

Tags: steam, system-requirements

With the PC build I am planning, I want to have a dedicated Hard drive for Steam. While I could just get the biggest Hard drive possible, I need to work out how much space I'll need at the very least for my current library (to see what my options are).

While I could just select every game in my library and download them all I already have some games installed currently which I keep installed for updates (ie. Terraria, Starbound) and to be honest I don't want to be uninstalling these only to have to re-download them (as my internet isn't all that fast)

I also have ~>300 games + DLC and while there is a System Requirement (Storage) on Games and DLC I believe that it only gives me the space requirement for the base game and not the DLC (ie. *Megadimension Neptunia VII* and one of it's DLC, the Weapons Pack, both say it takes 17 GB)

So is there a way to calculate how much Harddrive Space is needed for one's entire Steam Library (including DLC) without uninstalling it all?

Answer (score 3):

Try the Website [Steamgauge.com](https://www.mysteamgauge.com/):

Enter your username or id (if you set a custom id, you can use that too):

[image]

Result:

[image]